# Send a digitally signed mail with Joomla Mailer

Tags: php, email, joomla

I want send an email previosly signed with openssl_pkcs7_sign PHP function using the Joomla Mailer class.

Anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: Because the Joomla! Mailer is basically based on PHPMailer, search for a solution with the keyword "PHPMailer openssl_pkcs7_sign" and let us know the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

JMail extends from PHPMailer, so you can use every feature which is supported by PHPMailer.

In this case you should take a look at the Sign-function ([Joomla API](http://api.joomla.org/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.html#Sign)) 
You will find the project on GitHub ([PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer))

Example:

```
$mail = JFactory::getMailer();
$mail->Sign($cert_filename, $key_filename, $key_password);
```

Additional:

[sending secure certified (s/mime) emails via php using phpmailer](http://www.adam-makes-websites.com/discoveries/sending_secure_certified_s-mime_emails_via_php)